# Difference between numpy.linalg.lstsq and sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

As I understand, [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) and [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) both look for solutions `x` of the linear system `Ax = y`, that minimise the resdidual sum `||Ax - y||`.

But they don't give the same result:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
b = np.array([1, 0])
x , _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
x

Out[1]: array([ 1.,  0.])

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(A, b)                              
coef = clf.coef_
coef

Out[2]: array([ 0.5, -0.5])
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: As @cel nooted the only difference is the intercept. You can do `linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)` to get the same result as `np.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: A simple, but easy to overlook detail. Thanks!

Comment: If one of you would post the answer, I could mark this question answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of them are implemented by [LPACK gelsd](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/_gelsd.htm).

The difference is that `linear_model.LinearRegression` will do data pre-process (default) as below for input X (your A). But `np.linalg.lstsq` don't. You can refer to [the source code of LinearRegression](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L144) for more details about the data pre-process.

```
X = (X - X_offset) / X_scale
```

If you don't want the data pre-process, you should set `fit_intercept=False`.

Briefly speaking, if you normalize your input before linear regression, you will get the same result by both `linear_model.LinearRegression` and `np.linalg.lstsq` as below.

```
# Normalization/Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
A = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
X_scaler = StandardScaler()
A = X_scaler.fit_transform(A)
```

Now A is `array([[ 1., -1.],[-1.,  1.]])`

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

b = np.array([1, 0])
x , _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
x
Out[1]: array([ 0.25, -0.25])

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(A, b)                              
coef = clf.coef_
coef

Out[2]: array([ 0.25, -0.25])
```