Comparing specific linear regression functions in numpy, scipy, and sklearn: Differences in pre-processing and penalty functions
Looking at least-squares regression methods in various python libraries, and from their documentation and the two threads below (amongst others) is it right to say the following?

scipy.linalg.lstsq() and sklearn LinearRegression are effectively the same except that LinearRegression preprocesses the data. To prevent it doing so there's a parameter fit_intercept that can be set to False
The may or may not use different routines by default, depending on version, but if speed isn't an issue (small dataset & powerful computer) this doesn't matter
If coefficients should be positive (which is my case), LinearRegression has the parameter positive=True, and both scikit and numpy have nnls-methods

Remaing question: Is there any significant difference between the following, f.ex penalty function?  pre-processing? (my dataset is small'ish compared to many, all positive values, and coefficients ought to be positive, though first tests indicate that this occurs even when it's not specified in the method)

scipy.optimize.nnls
sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(positive=True, fit_intercept=False)
np.linalg.lstsq
scipy.linalg.lstsq

What is the difference between numpy.linalg.lstsq and scipy.linalg.lstsq?
Why using the scipy.nnls and the sklearn.linear_models.LinearRegression produces different results? Super Learner question
I have tried np.linalg.lstsq, sklearn LinearRegression(positve=True), and scipy.nnls. Comparing pre-processing (standardizing with sklearn StadardScalar) and not, the raw unprocessed data results in more accurate results.

Entirely correct, mea culpa, has been removed. Still doesn't answer my question. Do you know, please?

I'm not really sure what you're looking for in this question. What do you regard as a significant difference? e.g. NNLS has a very different algorithm than lstsq, as a result of the fact that it is restricted to positive coefficients. But if you don't care about performance and can assume that you have a problem where lstsq and NNLS provide the same solution, maybe you don't regard that as a significant difference.

It's hard to understand what you are asking. Please try editing your question so that there is only one, it is specific, and it can be answered fairly succinctly. E.g. What does "sklearn LinearRegression preprocesses the data" mean? (It does not, as far as I know.) What does "scikit and numpy have nnl methods" mean? It would help enormously if you would post a small, reproducible bit of code to help illustrate and leave out links to other questions unless you have something to say about them.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573046/difference-between-numpy-linalg-lstsq-and-sklearn-linear-model-linearregression (which linkts to a 404-page of supposedly source code on github) LinearRegression "will do data pre-process (default)". I have no other source for this though, it's not mentioned on the scikitlearn documentation, and is one of the things I hoped this thread would prove/disprove.

By significant I mean anything anyone more knowledgeable than I thinks a semi-newbie out to know :) Sorry, I can't ask a more specifici question without knowing more than I do (I don't know what I don't know)

@droneno.204 I fixed the link in that answer to point to the . That answer is still substantially correct, except that X_scale is always 1 in current versions of scikit-learn. (i.e. it reduces the variables to zero mean but does not convert them to a variance of 1.) Here is a link to the most recent version: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1.5.1/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L116

Thank you, that explains why sklearn-LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True) gave different result to ordinary lstsq on standardized data
